# Is it dangerous to give remote VNC access to a Server?

Tags: ssh, server, vnc

I have a Server powered by macOS Server on macOS Sierra. It serves as a file (AFP & SMB) server, VPN Server, and Web Server. It already has SSH enabled. I was wondering if it is safe to enable VNC file sharing on the remote Mac. You would be required to type in the Admin password to connect and then the same Admin password to login. My idea would be to set it up so it only allows access from a certain DDNS (XXXXXX.dddns.net, because I don't have a static address). And I would change the DDNS to the IP of where I would like to remotely access it.

I was wondering if this is safe and good practice. The other idea would be to VNC through an SSH tunnel.

Comment: For VNC, the best is to use SSH tunnel. Works really well. Also, I don't think you can filter VNC per DDNS. How exactly you want to do it?

Comment: VNC has very poor security by itself. You'd usually want to tunnel VNC with SSH. However, since you already have ssh server running, why not just use sftp or scp for file sharing?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. SSH tunnel is what I figured. As for the file sharing, I run the server for my family and unfortunately they don't know how to use  the command line and a desktop application is "too complicated" for them so I have just used the plain and simple SMB + AFP. But thanks for the suggestion maybe I can find someway to use those protocols.